# Could not access php file on core modules's external folder in social engine4

Tags: .htaccess, socialengine

I have installed the plugin 'Advanced Search Plugin Like Facebook Search' of younet and I noticed the error that application/modules/Core/externals/scripts/ynadvsearch.php is not found.

Then I checked the location and the file was there. So I uploaded a test.php file and typed the url in address bar then also I could not access the test.php page. But I am able to access all the js pages on that folder.

I have deleted the htaccess file of external folder. But the issue remains the same.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little weird, usually /externals/scripts folder is used only for javascript-files (and all php-files - inside of /controllers folder).

File .htaccess inside of /externals folder contains a rule

```
<FilesMatch   "\.avi|flv|mov|wmv|wma|mp3|mp4|m4a|mkv|swf|pdf|doc|ppt|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">`
```

It means that *.php files are not allowed for access inside of this folder.